# TableViews slides like iTunes store app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

How can I replicate this UI of iTunes app example picture (orange rectangle)?

I think in several options like multiple UITableViews, using a xib file and even combine HTML.

Can anyone help me with this challenge? I have a beginner experience in iOS development.

I'm using Objective-c for create an iPhone app for iOS 7 and 8 support.

[image: iTunes app example]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you a referring to switching/scrolling between "destacados" and "charts": in such situations, I am using a custom `TablesViewController` which in turn uses a `UISegmentedControl` and an `UIScrollView` with several `UITableView`s inside.

Comment: I'm referring to "Canciones nuevas" section that you can swipe between differents "TableViews" I think.

Comment: @isaiasmac yes, the answer applies (also) to this case.

Comment: Do you have a simple example please ?

Answer (score 0):

By using UIPageViewController you can easily get this functionality. Read the below link carefully for UIPageViewController tutorial.

http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/